# Only 8 activities returned for /me/activities query - where are the rest?

Tags: http, soundcloud

When I query /me/activities, the returned JSON only includes 8 tracks, then iterating over the next_href cursor attribute returns the same duplicate 8 tracks. I've used the same query as recently as a few weeks ago and was successfully able to return hundreds of songs, but I'm now limited to 8 songs.

To recreate:

`https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?limit=10&oauth_token=<token>`

`https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?limit=10&oauth_token=<token>&cursor=<cursor>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you still having the same problem?

Comment: Thanks Sam, I was able to get it working again using the Soundcloud-Python wrapper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't touched this problem since the end of March and wasn't able to replicate the issue today. I used the Souncloud-Python wrapper to return 1000+ songs:

```py
import soundcloud
client = soundcloud.Client(<client_id>, <client_secret>,
                           <username>, <password>)

total_activities = 0
next_href = '/me/activities?limit=25'

# Continue to fetch songs until no additional link is available
while next_href is not None:
    activities = client.get(next_href)
    per_req_count = 0
    for activity in activities.collection:
        # print "Found:", activity.type
        per_req_count += 1
    print('> per_req_count = {}'.format(per_req_count))
    total_activities += per_req_count
    next_href = activities.next_href

print('\n> total_activities = {}'.format(total_activities))
```